# Is a return statement necessary for try catch

Tags: vb.net, return, try-catch

I put a try/catch block around some email sending logic. If the email succeeds, it gives a confirmation message, if it fails, it gives a failure message. Visual Studio is warning me that the function doesn't return a value on all code paths. Do I need to put return statements in each the Try and Catch blocks? If I do, for example put Return statements of False or Null at the end of the Try and Catch, will the other code preceding the Return statements still execute?

```
Function Sendmail(ByVal subject As String, ByVal msg As String, ByVal fromAddress As String, ByVal toAddress As String)            
Try
                Dim message As New MailMessage
                message.From = New MailAddress(fromAddress)
                For Each s As String In toAddress.Split(New [Char]() {";"c})
                    message.To.Add(New MailAddress(s))
                Next
                message.Subject = subject
                message.Body = msg
                message.IsBodyHtml = False
                Dim client As New SmtpClient
                client.Send(message)
                pnlEmailSuccess.Visible = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                pnlEmailSuccess.Visible = False
                pnlEmailError.Visible = True
                lblErrorMsg.Text = ex.ToString
            End Try
End Function
```

Comment: If you don't need to return a value, change it to a `Sub` rather than a `Function`.

Comment: Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163814/will-statements-or-expressions-execute-after-a-return-statement-in-vb-net

Comment: You could add the return into the Finally, so it will be always run (if you need the return)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, No you do not need a `return` statement in a `Try/Catch`. If you are not returning a value you don't need to write it in a function. Instead of a writing this in a function you could write it in a `sub` statement or a `sub` procedure. Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx) to learn more about `sub` procedures.

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET expects that the last statement executed in a function is a Return that will send a value back to the calling procedure. When the code encounters a Return statement, it immediately terminates execution of the code and returns the value specified, which is why it's usually the last statement in the function (see below for example). VB.NET is just warning you that there is a possibility (in your case, a certainty, as there's only one exit point from the function) that the function won't be returning a value. As another example of when this might happen, consider a function that has two different paths by which the code could exit:

```
Function IsThisFive(ByVal x as Integer) as Boolean
    If x = 5 Then
        Return True 'One code path exits here, with return value
    Else
        MsgBox("This is not five!")
    End If
    ' Other code path exits here if x <> 5 -- no return value specified
End Function
```

To answer your question then, no, you don't need a return value inside both the Try and Catch blocks. You do, however, need one at the end of the block after End Try and before End Function. The code will run through Try..Catch..End Try construct, then Return a value.

If you don't need it to return a value, why not make it a sub rather than a function? A sub isn't expected to return a value, eliminating the problem. :-)

If you still wanted it to be a function, one common convention in programming is to only have a single exit point from a subroutine or function. This makes it easier to follow program flow when debugging or reading code.

You could do something like this:

```
Function SendMail(ByVal subject As String, ByVal msg As String, ByVal fromAddress As String, ByVal toAddress As String) as Boolean
    Dim maiLSent as Boolean = False
    Try
        'send mail code
        mailSent = True
    Catch
        'exception handling code here
        mailSent = False
    End Try

    Return mailSent ' Only exit point from function is here
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I added it to a timer with Try-Catch rather than continuously running. Worked perfectly.